# SQL LEFT JOIN confusion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pair of tables i need to join.

This query return 1164 records

```
SELECT name FROM tableA 
WHERE reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
```

And this one return 3339 records

```
SELECT name FROM tableB 
WHERE reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
```

Doing a LEFT JOIN should (according to various internet tutorials) return all the records in `tableA`, plus all the records in `tableB`, with a NULL where there's no matching row in `tableB`

However, this returns 1134 records. So 30 records from `tableA` are no longer being returned

```
SELECT tableA.name, tableB.name 
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.name = tableB.name
WHERE tableA.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
AND   tableB.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
```

Where am I going wrong? - I've checked that in both tables the 'name' field is unique by day (i.e. only one record per day)

To quote from the POSTGRES documentation

> LEFT OUTER JOIN returns all rows in the qualified Cartesian product
> (i.e., all combined rows that pass its join condition), plus one copy
> of each row in the left-hand table for which there was no right-hand
> row that passed the join condition.

I'll admit to being unsure about the meaning of "*the qualified Cartesian product*" but the 2nd half of the sentence seems to suggest I should get all the rows from `tableA` and NULLS where no match is found in `tableB`

UPDATE - bloody hell that was quick! Thanks guys, I should have asked earlier, would have saved an hour of my life.

Comment: Whenever you do a `LEFT JOIN` and you put a restriction on the right table (`tableB` in this example) in the `WHERE` clause you cause that `LEFT JOIN` to turn into an implicit `INNER JOIN`. Instead, move that `tableB.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'` condition into your `ON` clause, so that the restriction of records on `tableB` will occur BEFORE the join happens.

Comment: you are using `LEFT JOIN`, but documentation refers to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @Anton Those are different terms for the same behavior. Technically it's `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` is just shorthand.

Comment: @Anton, `LEFT JOIN` = `LEFT  OUTER JOIN`. `OUTER` is basically noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JNevill pointed out, the criteria has to be included inside the `ON` clause.

```sql
SELECT 
tableA.name, tableB.name 
FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB 
ON (tableA.name = tableB.name and tableB.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05')
WHERE tableA.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
```