# Full Outer Join failing to return all records from both tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a pair of tables I need to join, I want to return any record that's in tableA, tableB or both. I think I need a FULL OUTER JOIN

This query return 1164 records

```
SELECT name FROM tableA 
WHERE reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
```

And this one return 3339 records

```
SELECT name FROM tableB 
WHERE reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
```

And this one returns 3369 records (so there must be 30 records in tableA that aren't in tableB)

```
select distinct name FROM tableA where reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
union distinct
select distinct name FROM tableB where reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
```

I want to obtain a list of all matching records in either table. The query above returns 3369 records, so a FULL OUTER JOIN should also return 3369 rows (I think). My best effort so far is shown below. It returns 1164 rows and returns what looks to me to be a left join between tableA and tableB.

```
SELECT tableA.name.*, tableB.name.* 
FROM tableA
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB 
ON (tableA.name = tableB.name and tableB.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05')
WHERE tableA.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
```

Help appreciated. (if this looks question looks familiar, it's a follow-on question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71787272/sql-left-join-confusion) )

UPDATE - Sorry (@forpas) to keep moving the goalposts - I'm trying to match test data to real-data scenario's.

```
DROP TABLE tableA;
DROP TABLE tableB;

CREATE TABLE tableA (name         VARCHAR(10),
  reportDay    DATE, 
  val1         INTEGER,
  val2         INTEGER);

CREATE TABLE tableB (name         VARCHAR(10),
  reportDay    DATE, 
  test1        INTEGER,
  test2        INTEGER);

INSERT INTO tableA values  ('A','2022-Apr-05',1,2),  
('B','2022-Apr-05',3,4), ('C','2022-Apr-05',5,6), 
('A','2022-Apr-06',1,2), ('B','2022-Apr-06',3,4), 
('C','2022-Apr-06',5,6), ('Z','2022-Apr-04',5,6), 
('Z','2022-Apr-06',5,6) ;

INSERT INTO tableB values  ('A','2022-Apr-03',5,6), 
('B','2022-Apr-04',11,22), ('B','2022-Apr-05',11,22),  
('C','2022-Apr-05',33,44), ('D','2022-Apr-05',55,66), 
('B','2022-Apr-06',11,22), ('C','2022-Apr-06',33,44), 
('D','2022-Apr-06',55,66), ('Q','2022-Apr-06',5,6);

SELECT tableA.*, tableB.* 
FROM tableA
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB 
ON (tableA.name = tableB.name and tableB.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05'
AND  tableA.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05' )
```

For this data, I'd hope to see 4 rows of data 'A' from tableA only, 'B' and 'C' from both tables, and 'D' from table B only. I'm after the 5th April records only! The query (shown above) suggested by @forpas works except that the 'A' record in tableA doesn't get returned.

UPDATE - FINAL EDIT AND ANSWER!

Ok, the solution seem to be to concetenate the two fields together before joining....

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM tableA a FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b 
ON (b.name || b.reportDay) = (a.name || a.reportDay)
WHERE (a.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05' OR a.reportDay IS NULL)
  AND (b.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05' OR b.reportDay IS NULL);
```

Comment: You WHERE clause turns the outer join back into an inner join

Comment: Sample data would help your question.

Comment: Is `name` a primary key in one or both tables since you are `JOIN`ing on it? Otherwise your claim on 30 records (3369-3339) doesn't make sense, since the 3339 line query is not `DISTINCT` on name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition for the date should be placed in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM tableA a FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b 
ON b.name = a.name AND a.reportDay = b.reportDay 
WHERE '2022-Apr-05' IN (a.reportDay, b.reportDay);
```

or:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* 
FROM tableA a FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b 
ON b.name = a.name
WHERE (a.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05' OR a.reportDay IS NULL)
  AND (b.reportDay = '2022-Apr-05' OR b.reportDay IS NULL);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=853fbca016f4167db94b3c2a2fdb39a7).

Comment: Thanks @forpas. Both queries work for the initial set of test data I supplied, only the 2nd query works with the 2nd set of data I supplied. I'll do some further checks to see how it works on live data.

Comment: @ConanTheGerbil Your initial sample data did not cover all possible cases. This is why I posted 2 queries. I edited the 1st query so now both queries work for the new sample data.

Comment: Sorry for changing the data again. I'm trying to change the small sample to match all possible scenarios in real world data. The current data set is still missing a row even with the 2nd query.

Comment: @ConanTheGerbil did you check the demo I provide? It returns your expected results. Also the query in your question that you say that I propose has nothing to do with my code. I hope that you correct your claim.

Comment: sorry for any confusion. I checked your demo, it worked with the test data you had at the time. Your contribution was invaluable, the test data has changed several times as I have attempted to make it match all possible real-world scenarios. The solution currently listed in my last update is my answer but built on your suggestion. Thank you for your help

Comment: @ConanTheGerbil the 1st query works fine for your new sample data.